# control may reach end of non-void function. Frequency

Tags: c, frequency, cs50

I don't know why this program will not compile. It tells me there is a problem but I just do not know what is wrong with this code.

I am taking the CS50 introductory course for Harvard online and I am having trouble writing this function frequency. I know this can be coded much simpler but I just don't have the experience to make this much smoother and elegant in programming yet. The problem appears to be at the very end of the function. I am guessing I forgot to return a value but I do not know what is going on.

```
//Calculates frequency (in Hz) of a note

#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int frequency(string note);

int main(void)
{
string note = get_string();
printf("Piano Note: ");
frequency(note);
return 0;
}

int frequency(string note)
{
char key = note[0];
char accidental;
int octave;

int counter = 0;

while (note != '\0')
{
    counter++;
}

if(counter == 3)
    accidental = note[1];
    octave = note[2];
if(counter == 2)
    octave = note[1];

if (counter == 3)
{
    if (key == 'A')
    {
        if (accidental == '#')
        {
                if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 466;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 * pow((double)2, (double)1/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 * pow((double)2, (double)1/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }
        }

        else if (accidental == 'b')
        {
            if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 415;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)1/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)1/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }
        }
    }

    else if (key == 'B')
    {
        if (accidental == '#')
        {
            if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 523;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 * pow((double)2, (double)3/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 * pow((double)2, (double)3/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }

        else if (accidental == 'b')
        {
            if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 466;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 * pow((double)2, (double)1/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 * pow((double)2, (double)1/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }
    }

    else if (key == 'C')
    {
        if (accidental == '#')
        {
             if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 277;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)8/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if (octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)8/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }

        else if (accidental == 'b')
        {
             if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 247;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)10/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if (octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)10/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }
    }

    else if (key == 'D')
    {
        if (accidental == '#')
        {
            if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 311;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)6/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)6/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }

        else if (accidental == 'b')
        {
            if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 277;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)8/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)8/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }
    }

    else if (key == 'E')
    {
        if (accidental == '#')
        {
            if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 349;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)4/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)4/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }

        else if (accidental == 'b')
        {
            if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 311;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)6/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)6/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }
    }

    else if (key == 'F')
    {
        if (accidental == '#')
        {
             if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 370;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)3/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)3/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }}

        else if (accidental == 'b')
        {
             if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 330;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)5/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)5/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }
    }

    else if (key == 'G')
    {
        if (accidental == '#')
        {
             if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 415;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)1/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)1/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }

        else if (accidental == 'b')
        {
             if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 370;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)3/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)3/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
        }
    }
}

    if (counter == 2)
    {
            if(key == 'A')
            {

                if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 440;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int divisor = 0, hertz = 440;
                    while(divisor != count)
                    {
                        hertz /= 2;
                        divisor++;
                    }
                    return hertz;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int divisor = 0, hertz = 440;
                    while(divisor != count)
                    {
                        hertz *= 2;
                        divisor++;
                    }
                    return hertz;
                }
            }

            else if(key == 'B')
            {

                if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 494;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 * pow((double)2, (double)2/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 * pow((double)2, (double)2/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }
            }


            else if(key == 'C')
            {
                if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 262;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)9/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if (octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)9/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }
            }

            else if(key == 'D')
            {
                if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 294;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)7/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)7/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }
            }

            else if(key == 'E')
            {
                if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 330;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)5/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)5/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }
            }

            else if(key == 'F')
            {
                if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 349;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)3/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)3/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }
            }

            else if(key == 'G')
            {
                if(octave == 4)
                {
                    return 392;
                }

                else if(octave > 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i < octave; i++)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)2/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer *= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

                else if(octave < 4)
                {
                    int count = 0, shade = 0;
                    for(int i = 4; i > octave; i--)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    int answer = (440 / pow((double)2, (double)2/12));
                    while(shade != count)
                    {
                        answer /= 2;
                        shade++;
                    }
                    return answer;
                }

            }
    }
}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

Comment: *control may reach end of non-void function* means that you have a function that is a non-void function (meaning that it has to return some value) and there is a path where the function ends but no `return` statement was found. Think what happens when `counter' is greater than 3.

Comment: You told the compiler what to return when `counter` is 2 or 3, ***and*** `key` is a letter from A to G, ***and*** `accidental` is # or b. The compiler wants to know what it should return if, for example, `counter` is 1, or for another example, `counter` is 2 and `key` is H.

Comment: This cries out for the use of arrays and maybe a loop.  The hide for the octaves could go in a separate function, or written out once.

Comment: If you cleaned up the code to be more readable the answer would probably be obvious.`}}}}}}}}}}}}`

Comment: Holy mackarel ..

Comment: `if(counter == 3)     accidental = note[1];     octave = note[2];` is probably a bug (indentation does not control statement scope in C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While that code looks pretty bad to read, the compile error suggests that your function has a branch that will hit the end of function without a return statement.  If it seems like its working, add a default return value in the function, say int retVal = 0; then right before your function ends put the line return retVal;

I did not read through youre whole sample source code.  You may have if/elseif/elseif/etc without an else case which should return the default value too, which would through that compile type error.

If you dont want to return a default value return an error code and have the caller check for it to make sure its doing what you think its doing.

## edit, if counter == 1 for example, your function will not return anything.  That is one example of that the compiler is trying to tell you and there is probably more.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf("Piano Note: ");` in the
main function.  stdout may be line buffered, and without a trailing
newline, the output may not be actually sent to wherever stdout
is going, probably your screen.

More importantly, the following loop will never terminate (assuming
that note != '\0',

```
while (note != '\0')
{
    counter++;
}
```

if note != 0, the loop will be entered, but nothing inside the loop
updates note, so the condition will still be true, and the loop will
re-execute.

I don't see a definition of 'string' anywhere.  If this is a typedef
for 'char *', it's a terrible idea to do this, hiding the pointer
will lead to confusion.  If it's something else, then it's hard to
say what the behavior should be.  You compare it to a char, implying
that 'string' is a typedef for char, but that's not very useful,
if you're trying to get a string.

So you should lose the typedef, and get_string() should return
a char *, rather than 'string'.  I suspect the while loop is trying
to compute the length of the string.  Use strlen(3) for that.

I didn't count them, but it looks like you may have too many close braces
at the end.  The certainly don't line up with anything that would
make it easy to check visually.

Comment: Ah.  Good to know.  Especially unfortunate since "string" already has a (different, albeit related) meaning.